# When does an iphone application receive didChangeAuthorizationStatus: delegate call?

Tags: iphone, delegates, authorization, settings, cllocationmanager

I have a question about `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. The documentation says if the user changes the settings for your location services (in the iPhone's Settings.app) then your app is supposed to receive an `didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` message to the delegate. My question is, when would this happen?

If the user changed the setting, it means they are in the settings app, and your app is either backgrounded or not running at all, so in the former case, when would your app's `CLLocationManager` delegate get the `didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just ran across this method an hour ago, so good timing on the question!

It looks like in my case this method gets called:

1. When the app becomes active.
2. On allowing Location Services for the app on the initial startup of the app.

I wrote a quick test app you can find here:

https://github.com/mharper/LocationServices

It simply logs the authorization status whenever the method gets called.

Comment: This is helpful. From the Apple docs ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus: ), it seems as though this should only be called when the permissions change, but I agree with your assessment that this is also called whenever the app is launched, even if the permissions are untouched between launches.

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski Yes, the docs are wrong/incomplete.  I think the most correct answer is, it is also called when the location manager's delegate is first set which is usually when you launch your app.

Answer (score 6):

This delegate method will be called when:

1. The first time you init a `CLLocationManager` instance

   1.1. If that's the first time your App launch on device, you'll receive state `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` before user see the [Allow/Don't Allow] `UIAlertView`. (At this time, you can find that the `UISwitch` of your App in Settings - Privacy - Location Service is turn off or not shown.

   1.2. When user re-launch your App. Because decision has been made in previous launch, so you can retrieve the state.
2. The first time after user made decision. This is obvious. After you call the `startUpdatingLocation`/`startUpdatingHeading`, then iOS show the `UIAlertView`.
3. In your answer's situation, user made changes in Settings, if your App is running in background, you'll receive the new state when your App become active. Otherwise, reference 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is running in the background or not at all it will be called the moment the user returns to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue as well.

my solution is put the request gps authorization code in main loop.

I guess it can also works if you put in another run loop.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem of handling location permission changes correctly recently and did a lot of research and debugging.

If the app is not running at all and the user changes location permissions in Settings, then when you start your app, locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus is called when the location manager is initialized as stated in mharper's answer.  This behavior is not in Apple's docs.

If the app is in the background/suspended, I tested it in the simulator and it looks like the delegate function is also called.