# which is the delegate method for don't allow tap in "App would like to use your current location"?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, geolocation

I want to open a popup when user press Don't allow in the popup "App would like to use your current location". Is there any delegate method for that??

Comment: Have a look at this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266700/when-does-an-iphone-application-receive-didchangeauthorizationstatus-delegate-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't you dare reading the documentation...](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW14)

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        // FA1LZ
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `locationManager:didFailWithError:` and `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` of `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

First Need to get current Location. read this [documentation](http://tech.pro/tutorial/971/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application) for get current location.

And use this method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

**Parameters :**

**1 - manager**
         The location manager object reporting the event.
**2 - status**
         The new authorization status for the application.

**Use of This method**

This method is called whenever the application’s ability to use location services changes. Changes can occur because the user allowed or denied the use of location services for your application or for the system as a whole.

for more info read [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW14)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with below delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    if([error code]== kCLErrorDenied)
        self.locationDenied = YES;

        switch ([error code]) {
            // "Don't Allow" on two successive app launches is the same as saying "never allow". The user
            // can reset this for all apps by going to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location Warnings.
        case kCLErrorDenied:
            [appDelegate showAllowGPSLocationView];
        default:
            break;
        }

    self.locationDefined = NO;
}
```

When user will not allow GPS location, then above delegate method will be called. And you can check with "kCLErrorDenied" and handle whatever you want to do.

Here, "showAllowGPSLocationView" is method implemented in "AppDelegate" to inform the user to allow GPS location.

Hope, it will be helpful to you.

Happy Coding :)

Cheers!